# UTF-16LE txt file decode as String in Flutter (dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

To read a file contents of .txt file I am using

```
List<String> linesList = await file.readAsLines(encoding: latin1);
return linesList;
```

Files with Encodng UTF-8 are working perfectly with this above code.
But for Encoding UTF-16LE its returning a list with length double of the lines in the file but are all empty except first line. This first index contains ÿþ#

Comment: "Files with Encodng UTF-8 are working perfectly..." That seems very unlikely since you're reading the files using a Latin-1 encoding and not UTF-8.  If you want to read UTF-16LE files this way, then you will need to provide (and possibly implement) a UTF-16LE [`Encoding`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-convert/Encoding-class.html). (Storing files as UTF-16 is a bad idea and should be avoided if possible.)

Comment: There's a UTF16-LE decoder in the `utf` package. https://pub.dev/packages/utf

Comment: @jamesdlin I am not creating this file. I am using an imported file from some software and then extracting data from this file and saving it on the server.

Comment: @RichardHeap , I checked the utf package you mentioned in the comment. Its seems to be useful. I will look into this and will update. Thanks :)

Comment: @RichardHeap Thanks a lot . You had mentioned the right flutter package.Using this package I had been able to parse the file from any utf format and showing it as as String in the app. Thanks a lot again.It means a lot :)

Answer (score 8):

As `package:utf` is now abandoned (and therefore will never support null-safety), another way to read a UTF-16LE file as a `String` is to take advantage of Dart `String`s using UTF-16 code units internally.  You therefore can read the file, interpret the data as 16-bit (unsigned) integers, and then create a `String` using those as UTF-16 code units:

Basically:

```dart
var f = File("utf-16le.txt");
var bytes = f.readAsBytesSync();

// Note that this assumes that the system's native endianness is the same as
// the file's.
var utf16CodeUnits = bytes.buffer.asUint16List();

var s = String.fromCharCodes(utf16CodeUnits);
```

I also leave it as an exercise for the reader to deal with potential BOMs at the beginning of the file.

Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/convert/issues/30, which requests that the Dart SDK provide UTF-16 conversion functions.

Comment: You saved my day after hours of research, thanks!

Comment: For anyone wondering, to convert "utf-8" to "utf-8 with BOM" you only need to prepend [0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF] to your file bytes.

Answer (score 0):

So the first credit goes to @Richard_Heap , who has commented on the above question. He mentioned a dart package that encodes and decodes UTF formats. I have been able to decode the txt files as expected in my Flutter app using this package.

First I am identifying the utf format type by these functions available from the package mentioned by @Richard_Heap

```
 List<int> bytes = await file.readAsBytes();

hasUtf16beBom(bytes)
hasUtf16Bom(bytes)}
hasUtf16leBom(bytes)
hasUtf32beBom(bytes)
hasUtf32Bom(bytes)
hasUtf32leBom(bytes)
```

There are different decoder & encoder functions in this package that can be used once the utf format is known using these above functions. Like I used

```
String decodedString = decodeUtf16le(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [charset](https://pub.dev/packages/charset) package. It is null-safe and supports both UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE according to [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/charset/latest/charset/Utf16Decoder-class.html).

Usage:

```
import 'package:charset/charset.dart';

main() {
  // default
  print(utf16.decode([254, 255, 78, 10, 85, 132, 130, 229, 108, 52]));

  print(utf16.encode("上善若水"));

  // detect
  print(hasUtf16Bom([0xFE, 0xFF, 0x6C, 0x34]));

  // advance
  Utf16Encoder encoder = utf16.encoder as Utf16Encoder;
  print(encoder.encodeUtf16Be("上善若水", false));
  print(encoder.encodeUtf16Le("上善若水", true));
}
```