# Dart/Flutter UTF-16 encoding

Tags: java, flutter, dart, character-encoding, utf

I need to read in a file that's been saved in Java Android Studio with this code

```
fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
os.writeObject(json);
os.close();
fos.close();
```

It turns out that Java uses internally UTF-16 for encoding the characters. I now need to read this files in Flutter SDK (with the Dart language)

```
file.readAsString(encoding: Latin1).then((str) => {
       print(str)
     }).catchError( (e) => {
       print(e)
});
```

However, the Latin1 encoding doesn't work perfectly. So I want to read it in using UTF-16 but it seems that Dart does simply not have this functionality, or at least not that I can find.

`Utf8Codec` does exist but there's not `Utf16Codec` nor `Encoding.getByName("UTF-16")`. Utf8 is by the way giving exceptions so this is also no option.

So how can I still read in files in Dart which have been saved in Android Studio Java using UTF-16?

Comment: Based on your other question, I'd guess that the bytes are *not* in UTF-16, but just have a Java object stream prefix.

Comment: You probably would be interested in this related question: [UTF-16LE txt file decode as String in Flutter (dart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943867/utf-16le-txt-file-decode-as-string-in-flutter-dart)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `utf` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/utf).

```
  var bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  var decoder = Utf16BytesToCodeUnitsDecoder(bytes); // use le variant if no BOM
  var string = String.fromCharCodes(decoder.decodeRest());
```

Comment: that package is discontinued

Comment: I discovered that it still works though. Lucky because it solved a big problem, Phew!

Comment: utf  package is discontinued

Answer (score 1):

```
  final File file = File(filePath);

  final bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();

  final utf16CodeUnits = bytes.buffer.asUint16List();

  final s = String.fromCharCodes(utf16CodeUnits);
```

I was able to turn a UTF-16 file into a String using these 4 lines to avoid using the discontinued package. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -4):

Use Base64. Importing  **'dart:convert'**.

```
  var bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  final encoded = base64.encode(bytes);
  debugPrint("onPressed " + encoded);
```

Comment: Base64 has nothing to do with UTF-16.