# Read UTF-16 LE file in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to read a file formated as UTF-16 LE

```
new File(filePath)
        .openRead()
        .map(utf8.decode)
        .transform(new LineSplitter())
        .forEach((l) => print('line: $l'));
```

But I get this error `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid UTF-8 byte`
I've also tried to use this package `utf: ^0.9.0+5` but it's not an option cause of null safety.
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `utf8.decode` decodes UTF-8 data, so it doesn't make sense to use it on UTF-16LE data.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802971/ for a way to read a UTF-16LE file as a `String`.

Comment: thanks for the link, i'm able to read it now