# How to encode to UTF16 Little Endian in Dart?

Tags: dart, utf-16le

I am attempting to manipulate some system variables used by a program using Dart.  I have encountered the problem of [dart's utf](https://pub.dev/packages/utf) package being discontinued, and I have not found any way to encode to UTF 16 Little Endian for a [File](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-io/File-class.html).write.  Is there a library that can do a byte to UTF 16 LE conversion in Dart?  I would use UTF anyway, but it is not null safe.  I may end up trying to use the utf package source code, but I am checking here to see if there is a native (or pub) implementation I have missed, as I am new to the world of UTF and byte conversions.

My goal:

```
encodeAsUtf16le(String s);
```

I do not need to write a BOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart `String`s internally use UTF-16.  You can use [`String.codeUnits`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/codeUnits.html) to get the UTF-16 code units and then write them in little-endian form:

```dart
  var s = '\u{1F4A9}';
  var codeUnits = s.codeUnits;
  var byteData = ByteData(codeUnits.length * 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < codeUnits.length; i += 1) {
    byteData.setUint16(i * 2, codeUnits[i], Endian.little);
  }
  
  var bytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  await File('output').writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

or assume that you're running on a little-endian system:

```dart
  var s = '\u{1F4A9}';
  var codeUnits = s.codeUnits;
  var bytes = Uint16List.fromList(codeUnits).buffer.asUint8List();
  await File('output').writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802971/, which is about encoding UTF-16LE to `String`s.

I also feel compelled to advise *against* writing UTF-16 to disk unless you're forced to by external requirements.

Comment: Yes, a bootloader I am creating a program for reads UTF-16 data to the EFI partition upon boot up and writes the user selection to the file.  Your method worked perfectly, thank you.