# Encoding UFT16 Emoji returns invalid bytes

Tags: flutter, dart, parsing, unicode, utf-16

I am trying to encode a Unicode character in dart, but this results in an invalid byte array.

The character:

The bytes: [FF, FE, 3D, D8, 25, DD]

The string is encoded with BOM. After decoding this string I can see that the string is parsed correctly, resulting to see the emoji inside my IDE.

Then I try to encode the String again but that gives me a byte array, I don't understand:

[FF, FE, FD, FF, FD, FF]

I am using the package [utf_convert](https://pub.dev/packages/utf_convert) to encode the string:

```dart
import 'package:utf_convert/utf_convert.dart' as utf;

List<int> convert(String input) {
  return utf.encodeUtf16le(input, true).cast<int>();
}
```

Is this a bug inside this package, or am I overseeing something here?

## Edit1

I wrote some simple tests to capture the problem:

```dart
void main() {
  var emojiString = '';
  var emojiBytes = <int>[0xFF, 0xFE, 0x3D, 0xD8, 0x25, 0xDD];

  test('Decode Emoji', () {
    var emoji = utf.decodeUtf16le(emojiBytes);

    expect(emoji, emojiString);
  });

  test('Encode Emoji', () {
    var bytes = utf.encodeUtf16le(emojiString, true).cast<int>();

    expect(bytes, emojiBytes);
  });
}
```

The function "Decode Emoji" succeeds, but the second one, "Encode Emoji" fails with the assertion:

*Expected: [255, 254, 61, 216, 37, 221] Actual: [255, 254, 253, 255, 253, 255]*

Comment: I have some problem to understand what you are doing. Usually we use unicode as hex sequences. On your result you have *BOM + replacement character + replacement character*. But why a byte (input) is 516? This seems out of range, or you are using a strange notation. Check it. (and write numbers in hexadecimal)

Comment: 516 was a typing mistake, it was 216. I have changed the characters to Hex codes for better reading

Comment: The bytes: [FF, FE, 3D, D8, 25, DD] are (in *Utf16le*)) - `` (U+FEFF,  *Zero Width No-Break Space **(BOM)***)
- `` (U+D83D,  *Non Private Use High Surrogate*)
- `` (U+DD25,  *Low Surrogate*). Surrogate pairs is a way to encode codepoints above BMP in UTF-16: `` (U+1F525, *FIRE (0xd83d,0xdd25)*).

Comment: Check the output. i think now you incorrectly replaced the second 253 into FE. There is something strange; your output contain a BOM, but documentation tall that `utf.encodeUtf16le` should not add a BOM. (remove the `le` to get the BOM. Just to be sure, could you make a complete example: defining `input`, using your function and printing output. Possibly there is a wrong assumption on one of the steps

Comment: Where are the bytes *FF, FE, 3D, D8, 25, DD* from? How do they relate to your question? They are already UTF-16 encoding the fire emoji (plus BOM), except each 16-bit code unit is broken down into 2 bytes each. `encodeUtf16le` will just destroy it.

Comment: @Codo I am encoding the emoji cahracter, , not the Hex itself.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I will write some test functions and show the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing a lot of researching, I think this is a bug within this library. The code found there is a fork of a discontinued package  found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/utf).

The solution I did now, was using some other piece of code, still existing inside the dart library. I found a hint inside [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68089811/how-to-encode-to-utf16-little-endian-in-dart) SO post.

Then I implemented a new library on my own, which others facing the same issue can use too. I hosted it on [GitHub](https://github.com/zooper-lib/zooper_flutter_encoding_utf16) and [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/zooper_flutter_encoding_utf16) under MIT license.