# How to handle Exception: ArchiveException('Invalid GZip Signature')

Tags: android, flutter, gzip, archive, utf-16

I am trying to decode the bytes using `GZipDecoder().decodeBytes` from the [archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) package and I am getting this exception:

```
ArchiveException('Invalid GZip Signature')
```

How should I handle this exception? I am getting the `List<int>` data using a decoder method `Utf16leBytesToCodeUnitsDecoder(zippedBytes).decodeRest()` from the [Utf](https://pub.dev/packages/utf) package.

**Version**

- Platform: Android
- Flutter: 2.10.4
- archive: ^3.3.0

Do let me know if more info is required. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated!

---

> @MarkAdler Then it's not gzip input.

The steps are overall steps as well from picking the file to reading it that I am using. Thanks to MarkAdler for his comment!:

1. Convert the file into `Unint8List` by reading the file with `var bytes = File(_path).readAsBytesSync()`
2. Decoding the Utfle16 bytes to Utf8 bytes by `Utf16leBytesToCodeUnitsDecoder(bytes)`
3. Finally using `GZipDecoder().decodeBytes` which throws the error.

Comment: Then it's not gzip input.

Comment: @MarkAdler Thanks for your comment on this. I tried to determine if that's the case by looking the using the `file -i sample.csv.gz` in Linux terminal. The repose was:
```
sample.csv.gz: application/gzip; charset=binary
```

Since the actual implementation is done on the Flutter application. The steps are:
1) Convert the file into `Unint8List` by reading the file with `var bytes = File(_path).readAsBytesSync()`
2) Decoding the Utfle16 bytes to Utf8 bytes by `Utf16leBytesToCodeUnitsDecoder(bytes)`
3) Finally using `GZipDecoder().decodeBytes` which throws the error.

Comment: Hope this information is useful in understanding the problem better. I am putting in the question as well to provide the info in better formatting. You can be right even. Please let me know if there is any other way I can verify the input

Comment: Why are you doing UTF conversions? You have read the bytes as bytes. Feed those directly to the gzip decoder.

Comment: @MarkAdler Your final comment helped me. Thanks a lot. I changed the order of the instructions. 1) read the bytes 2) Passed the bytes as input to gzip encoder 3) performed the conversion to UTF-8.

To answer the question you asked. Because the data is in UTF-16LE, I am unable to parse the data into appropriate types. That is the reason I had to do conversation. Or at least I believe so. Since it worked this way for me.

Comment: But the thing that I am still not able to understand is the reason.  Why it was not working when conversion is performed first. Also, for the past 3 months or so I have been using the earlier mentioned code and things worked as intended without any issue. Can you think of the possible reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: Now why are you doing step 3?! (Conversion to UTF-8.) That can prevent you from decompressing the gzip stream at the other end. Leave binary data alone. Stop trying to corrupt it with unicode conversions.

Comment: @MarkAdler I am doing step 3 on the decompressed bytes that I received from step 2. Please let me if it can still corrupt the data in some form. Coming to the question as to why I am doing the conversion. I believe [UTF-16LE txt file decode as String in Flutter (dart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943867/utf-16le-txt-file-decode-as-string-in-flutter-dart) question is able to explain the outcome in a better way if I don't do the conversion.

Comment: While going through the responses to the shared question, I liked the idea of directly reading the `UTF-16LE` file as a `String` in dart. And since the file I am using is `UTF-16LE` that shouldn't be the problem but I don't why it just didn't worked in my situation. I will try to do a bit more study on this perhaps!